# Editing view for combined form and inline_formset

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

I have been trying to create an editing view that allows me manage both parent and child models using an inline formset based in the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-an-inline-formset-in-a-view)

From what I can appreciate the formset doesn't validate. I did try and change it so that instead of validating the entire formset it iterated through each individual form in the formset and validated them individually. This did allow me to add items to the formset but not delete them.

At the moment the code results in "didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead" value error as the redirect is in the If valid statement and so if that does not result in true there is no other redirect to fall back on.

#### Models

```py
class Shoppinglist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True) 
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='lists', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    shoppinglist = models.ForeignKey(Shoppinglist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

#### URL

```py
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^shoppinglists/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', views.shoppinglist_edit, name='shoppinglist_edit'),
]
```

#### View

```py
def shoppinglist_edit(request, pk):

    try:
        shoppinglist = Shoppinglist.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except ShoppingList.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    
    ItemInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(Shoppinglist, Item, extra=1, fields=('name', 'amount'))

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ShoppinglistForm(request.POST, instance=shoppinglist)
        formset = ItemInlineFormset(request.POST, instance=shoppinglist)

        if formset.is_valid() and form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            formset.save()
            return redirect('packlist_list', pk=pk)    

    else:
        form = ShoppinglistForm(instance=shoppinglist)
        formset = ItemInlineFormset(instance=shoppinglist)

        context = {
            'shoppinglist' : shoppinglist,
            'listform': form, 
            'formset': formset,
            }

        return render(request, 'edit_list_with_items.html', context)
```

#### Template

```py
{% block content %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <label>List Name</label>
    {{ listform.name }}
    {% if listform.first_name.errors %}
        {% for error in listform.first_name.errors %}
            {{ error|escape }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    <label>Description</label>
    {{ listform.description }}
    {% if listform.description.errors %}
        {% for error in listform.description.errors %}
            {{ error|escape }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    {{ formset.management_form }}

    {% for form in formset %}
        <div class="item-formset">
            {{ form.amount }}
            {% if form.amount.errors %}
                {% for error in form.amount.errors %}
                    {{ error|escape }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

            {{ form.name }}
            {% if form.name.errors %}
                {% for error in form.name.errors %}
                    {{ error|escape }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    {% if formset.non_form_errors %}
        {% for error in formset.non_form_errors %}
            {{ error|escape }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    <div class="row spacer">       
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Create</button>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_js %}
<script>
  $('.item-formset').formset({
      addText: 'add item',
      deleteText: 'remove'
  });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Please note I am using this jquery plugin in the template.

https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is probably either your form or formset is invalid, and you dont use `else` statement to handle that.

so in your **views.py**:

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ShoppinglistForm(request.POST, instance=shoppinglist)
        formset = ItemInlineFormset(request.POST, instance=shoppinglist)

        if formset.is_valid() and form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            formset.save()
            return redirect('packlist_list', pk=pk)    
        else:
            # either your form or formset is invalid, so this code will render it again.
            context = {
              'shoppinglist' : shoppinglist,
              'listform': form, 
              'formset': formset,
            }

            return render(request, 'edit_list_with_items.html', context)
    else:
        form = ShoppinglistForm(instance=shoppinglist)
        formset = ItemInlineFormset(instance=shoppinglist)

        context = {
            'shoppinglist' : shoppinglist,
            'listform': form, 
            'formset': formset,
            }

        return render(request, 'edit_list_with_items.html', context)
```

or you can simplify it with this:

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ShoppinglistForm(request.POST, instance=shoppinglist)
        formset = ItemInlineFormset(request.POST, instance=shoppinglist)

        if formset.is_valid() and form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            formset.save()
            return redirect('packlist_list', pk=pk)    
    else:
        form = ShoppinglistForm(instance=shoppinglist)
        formset = ItemInlineFormset(instance=shoppinglist)
    # notice the indentation
    context = {
        'shoppinglist' : shoppinglist,
        'listform': form, 
        'formset': formset,
    }

    return render(request, 'edit_list_with_items.html', context)
```

Comment: I have tried the simplified implementation and it has worked. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned error coming because you write this `return render(request, 'edit_list_with_items.html', context)` inside else block.

instead of this:

```
else:
        form = ShoppinglistForm(instance=shoppinglist)
        formset = ItemInlineFormset(instance=shoppinglist)

        context = {
            '
            }

        return render(request, 'edit_list_with_items.html', context)
```

Do this:

```
else:
        form = ShoppinglistForm(instance=shoppinglist)
        formset = ItemInlineFormset(instance=shoppinglist)

        context = {

            }

return render(request, 'edit_list_with_items.html', context)
```

Comment: I'm afraid when if I put the return render(request, 'edit_list_with_items.html', context) outside of the block I get the following error "local variable 'context' referenced before assignment"